# Can Shaivaites or Devotees of Shiva eat meat?

Tags: shiva, belief, food, shaivism

I have seen animals sacrificing for  Kali mata. I am not brahmin by birth but had developed interest towards Lord Siva. I read Shiva Purana but there are no references for devotees of Shiva. I have read story of Bhaktha kannappa. Can Shaivaites eat meat?

Comment: @AnilKumar If you have read story of Kannappa, you should know that Kannappa's way of offerings was not usual as opposed to others. Although Kannappa offered meat to Lord Shiva out of sheer dedication, the temple priest see the meat offerings with disgust. This shows that originally in that part Lord Shiva was not offered meat but it is devotees who might be unaware and whatever they feel is good are offering.

Comment: Btw, people's beliefs differ according to places. At some places, offering meat is ok and allowed while at other places it is forbidden and taken as an offense. Mostly i see it as whatever people are eating in a particular region and not consider offensive, they use in offering to Gods as well. So, God's diet we don't know but its actually people's diet what they offer to God.

Comment: Lord Shiva does not eat meat. None of the gods eat meat or other stuff because they do not have bodies made of five elements. They accept oblations made in yagna fire with mantra. You may continue your dietary practices according to the caste you were born into. Just remember not to partake on forbidden days like Sunday(adhi devata being Shiva), ekadasi , etc. Unless you have been initiated into a mantra. Then your mantra guru will guide you regarding the prescribed lifestyle.

Comment: According to Shiva purana, those who perform rite of listening Shiva purana shouldn't eat meat.

Answer (score 6):

Can one eat meat and still be a devotee ? The answer to this question will be **Yes**.

But, if the question is whether Lord Shiva approves such an act? (which is what a true devotee will be more concerned about)  then the answer will be **No**.

Lord Shiva does not approve meat eating unless it is part of some rituals.

This is what he says to Sri Devi:

> Pitridevatayajneshu VaidahimsA Vidhiyate |
>
> **AtmArtham PrAninAm HimsA kadAchinnoditA Priye** ||
>
> .....
>
> In Pitru Yanjna and Deva Yajnas sacrificial killing is allowed. But
>   other than that the Shastras never allow prani himsa (killing) for
>   one's own pleasure.
>
> **KulArnava Tantram, Chapter 5, Verse 45.**

So, it is clear that Lord Shiva does not like the idea of his devotees eating non-sacrificial meat.

Eating meat is allowed only if it is part of some ritual.

Comment: Notice "for one's own pleasure", it might be prohibiting leisure hunting instead of meat eating.

Answer (score 4):

Kashmiri Pandits worship a variation of Shiva known as Batuka Bhairava - with fish and meat.

Vamachara maarg of Tantra is inclined towards the Five M's -

1. Madya (wine)
2. Mamsa (meat)
3. Matsya (fish)
4. Mudra (cereal)
5. Maithuna (sexual intercourse)

Here we can understand it is meat.

Also in Ashwamedh and Purushmedh yagna sacrifices are made and deities are offered meats. So we can consider Shiva may eat meat.

Also in Ramayana Later, Sita said to Ravana (disguised as a sage):

> "Āgamiṣyati me bharta vanyamādāya puṣkalam z
>   Rurūṇ godhān varāhāñca hatvā ādāyāmiṣaṃ vahu  zz
>   Sa tvaṃ nāma ca gotraṃ kulamācakṣava tatvataḥ z 
>   Ekaśca daṇḍakāraṇye kimartha carasi dvija zz"  (Araṇya/47/23-24)

Translation:

> "My husband Ram will come back soon with many kinds of wild fruits and plentiful of meat by hunting ruru (a kind of deer), varaha (wild boar) and godha (iguana). Now you please be kind and tell me your name, your gotra (clan or lineage) to which you belong and what you are roaming in this lonely forest for?" (tr. Ibid, p-323).

There are several other verses that suggest that Ram was not vegetarian. This is also one proof that GODs eat meat.

God is so simple, He is our Aid /wellwisher, who accepts whatever we offer Him with LOVE.

In most of the stories or myths related to temples it could be seen that when the installation of the idol is completed the related people worship the idol with whatever they have in their home.

So, people staying near sea and depending on the sea for their living, naturally will have dried fish as a stock of food at their home. If this community installs an idol in their village, definitely, this dried fish can be expected as an offering.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But some people say Rama never ate meat. It was due to wrong translation. If Rama and Krishna had really eaten meat, then it wouldn't be a sin for people who want Rajo guna .

Comment: But here food was offered first to God and ate by people later, similar to Grama devatas. But my question is can I eat meat without offering to Lord Shiva?

Comment: @AnilKumar That's your personal interest to offer or not.

Comment: @TheDestroyer - any food we eat must be offered to God first. Not because God is hungry (although he will be hungry if you really want him to be as a bhakta), but to remove the food's doshas. When preparing even vegetarian food, there are many places of ahimsa - grinder, stove, broom, waterpot etc where insects die. When cultivating the land, animals get crushed, when transporting grains via road/train also animals get killed. To pacify these insect's souls, we do neivedyam to God.. otherwise we eat only sin (bhagavad gita).

Comment: @TheDestroyer, the story of Vishvamitra - after 12 years of no rain, he was about to die and could only find food from svapaka (chandala or dog eater). Before he was about to eat it, [he offered it to devas](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12a140.htm). Pleased by his devotion even in times of distress, Indra poured rain and revived the earth. Even though you're not Brahmin, it is said a person who shuns meat, all the beings will bow to him. It also leads to rajo/tamo guna which hinders spiritual thoughts and creates animalistic desires.

Comment: @TheDestroyer, there are many other doshas associated with food - the person who cultivated it, who transported it, who cooked it, who served it, must all be of clean body and heart, otherwise some of their doshas are transferred to the food. By offering to God, it is a sacrifice (yaga, also called Ijya in brahmin tradition), and that cleanses the food of doshas. I've heard this is several upanyasams, and Ahara Niyama also mentions it. And naturally, we only offer clean and good food to lord, like fruits, nuts, sweets, while meat, why even onion/garlic, is frowned upon in religious households

Comment: @ram Thanks! Actually i asked this question, when i joined this site. Now, i know correct answer.

Comment: @TheDestroyer , oh haha, didn't see the question date. it surfaced on main page probably due to some edit, so i thought it was new

Comment: @Mr.P. Thank you for the answer. But don't you think even for the deer, god is god. God never kills us or eat us for satisfying his appetite. To visualise him as a human and still thinking that just like a human being, he was eating other animal's meat, isn't that too biased? How can god just eat one living creature's meat that he created himself with love?

Answer (score 2):

Pandavas were voracious meat eaters according to Mahabharata.

> Mahabharata Vana Parva Section CCLVI says, "Once on a time, as
>   Yudhisthira lay down at night in the Dwaita woods, some deer, with
>   accents choked in tears, presented themselves before him in his
>   dreams. To them standing with joined hands, their bodies trembling all
>   over, that foremost of monarchs said, 'Tell me what ye wish to say.
>   Who are ye? And what do ye desire?" Thus accosted by Kunti's son - the
>   illustrious Pandava, these deer, the remnant of those that had been
>   slaughtered, replied unto him, saying, 'We are, O Bharata, those deer
>   that are still alive after them that had been slaughtered. We shall be
>   exterminated totally. Therefore, do thou change thy residence. O
>   mighty king, all thy brothers are heroes, conversant with weapons;
>   they have thinned the ranks of the rangers of the forest. We few - the
>   remnants,-O mighty minded one, remain like seed. By thy favour, O king
>   of kings, let us increase.' Seeing these deer, which remained like
>   seed after the rest has been destroyed trembling and afflicted with
>   fear, Yudhisthira the just was greatly affected with grief. And the
>   king, intent on the welfare of all creatures, said unto them, ' So be
>   it. I shall act as ye have said.' Awaking after such a vision, that
>   excellent king, moved by pity towards the deer, thus spake unto his
>   brothers assembled there, 'Those deer that are alive after them that
>   have been slaughtered, accosted me at night, after I had wakened,
>   saying, 'We remain like the cues of our lines. Blest be thou! Do thou
>   have compassion on us. And they have spoken truly. We ought to feel
>   pity for the dwellers of the forest. We have been feeding on them for
>   a year together and eight months. Let us, therefore, again (repair) to
>   the romantic Kamakhyas, the best of forests abounding in wild animals,
>   situated at the head of the desert, near Lake Trinavindu. And there
>   let us pleasantly pass the rest of our time.'

At least Arjuna among the Pandavas worshipped Shiva.

Answer (score 1):

The Answer would vary depending upon the sub-sect of Shaivism.

But Tirumantiram, one of the most important texts of Shaiva siddhanta written by Tirumular (One of the 63 Nayanmars) and seen as the essence of Shaivagamas clearly criticises Meat eating as well as drinking as sinful and a sin leading to hell.

**--- Tirumantiram Tantra 1 ---**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The rules vary depending upon the subsect as already stated in the other answers.

I shall be covering the stance of the pAshupata sampradaya on the matter. While the pa~nchArthika pAshupatas (led by kauNDinya has almost Jaina alias shramaNa like tremendous emphasis on ahiMsA; The same pAshupata sUtra-s, asserting the existence of a different stream of the same pAshupata sampradAya from the above mentioned one, allows it's initiates to eat buffalos, boars, goats etc. If they are given as alms. Which means they themselves can't hunt but can eat it, if given by someone else.

Quoting Directly from Sri kauNDinya's commentary on the pAshupata Sutra.

### Pasupata Sutra V.16

[image]

English translation-

[image]

Key verse - यस्य माहिषवाराहादीनाम् अन्यतमम् यत् प्राप्यते तत् खलु हिंसास्तेयरहितत्वात्॥

This pAshupata seems to be represented by shrI haraprabodha who's a contemporary to a Jaina alias shramaNa called chaNDakarmana. This episode is found in the "yashastilaka" ,written by another Jaina called "somadeva suri" of 10th century CE . The verse is-

> **अग्निवत् सर्वभक्षोsपि भवभक्तिपरायणः।भुक्तिं जीवन्नवाप्नोति मुक्तिं तु लभते मृतः ॥**
>
> [Translation]'One who is devoted to shiva obtains pleasure in life and
> release on death, even though he is omnivorous like Fire.'

The saura purANa, a shaiva shAstra,embodies this stand.

### Saura Purana Chapter 11

> **ईश्वर उवाच - मद्भक्तः सर्वदा स्कन्द मत्प्रियो न गुणाधिकः । सर्वाशी सर्वभक्षी वा सर्वाचारविलोपकः ॥५॥**
>
> [Translation] Shiva says - "My devotee, though may be omnivorous, eats
> anything and everything, is still the dearest to
> me".

Answer (score 0):

Eating for survival is individual survival and well being depending upon environments and work culture. But, a Hindu has commitments towards God.

You can see communities/religions seek refuge and live in India because in their countries they dont actually worship God. Their worship is not sufficient to protect themselves from calamities - cyclones, forest fires, genocides, wars and ethic / race clashes similar to our national conflicts by people.

Only a Hindu can lead a beautiful mindset towards God.

Apologies to sainthood of other religions. Saints globally are beyond what is written.

Eating meat is restricted for priesthood(Divine ritual facilitators) and antima-samskaaram(death ritual facilitators), Gurus (spiritual & scientific teachers), doctors(who are with humans during their death / trying to heal human suffering).

If above four classes eat meat they can never save humans from heavy suffering. Four classes of jobs are not exhibitions of rage/valour or power.

Vaishnavites & Shaivaites in above mentioned four classes of jobs must avoid meat & slaughter house products to maximum possible limits of their survival.

Answer (score 0):

**linga purANa uttarabhaga ch. 78 :**

> *11-15a. Those who protect persons of various sorts like a loving master or with love as if they were their own sons and grandsons, go
> to the world of Rudra. Hence, by all means sprinkling should be
> performed by means of water filtered with a cloth. The ablution should
> be carried out particularly. Even by killing a single person in the
> premises of Śiva’s temple one attains the sins that accrue from
> destroying the three worlds. But, O excellent brahmins, violence to
> flowers must always be pursued for the **worship of Śiva**, **violence
> to the animals for the sake of sacrifice**. The chastisement of the
> wicked by the Kṣatriya caste can be pursued.*